# Create new bit column based on string evaluation

Tags: string, t-sql, contains

I was looking into the function `Contains` but it can only be used in the Where predicate, what I'm looking for is something of the sorts

```
Select doc.* , IsSync = StringContains('Sync', doc.Url) from vw_Doc as doc
```

IsSync now would contain 1/0 or true/false, depending if the word Sync exists in the document Url.

Is this at all possible ?

Thank you for your time

Edit: `StringContains` is meant as a pseudo-function, it's not valid syntax

Comment: What is "StringContains"? Doesn't seem like a built in function. Do you mean [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use case and charindex().

```
select 
    doc.* , 
    case
        when charindex('Sync', doc.Url) > 0
            then 1
            else 0
        end as IsSync
from 
    vw_Doc as doc
```

Comment: Aside: It's worth noting that [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) does word matching on a full-text index rather than simple character matching. It would not find the word "tithe" in "antithetical" whereas a simple test using `CharIndex` cheerfully reports a match.

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` is not limited to a `where` clause, it returns a [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) that can be used in various contexts, e.g.:

```
select *,
  case when Contains( doc.url, 'Sync' ) then 1 else 0 end as IsSync
  from vw_Doc;
```